# Is Google App Engine's Webapp Framework Open Source? Is it available outside GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, web-applications

Google App Engine includes this minimal framework called "webapp". Google Code does not list a project page for webapp. The only documentation/information from Google on webapp is in the Google App Engine documentation. Is webapp not usable outside GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use webapp outside App Engine - there's very little that's App Engine specific - but it's not designed for it, and thus isn't packaged or documented separately. If you want a webapp-like framework you can use anywhere, check out [webapp2](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/). It's a very close copy of webapp, with a lot of improvements and extensions. In fact, we (the App Engine team) like it so much it's the official replacement for Webapp on the Python 2.7 platform!

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if webapp2 plays well with greenlet based Python servers?

Comment: @pokstad I'm not familiar with greenlet. Webapp2 should work fine with any server that can run WSGI or CGI apps.